# Sending compiled objects to Closure Templates

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-templates

If I call a template from JavaScript with:

```
namespace.template(record);
```

where `record` is an instance of:

```
/** @typedef {{var: string}} */
```

and I use the Google Closure Compiler in advanced mode, which rewrites `var`, then how can I receive `var` in the template? Is using `'var'` instead of `var` to prevent rewriting the only way to do this?

I'm thinking that, ideally, it would be nice if I could provide types for the template's `@param`s, just like I can for the JavaScript code, which should let the compiler know what rewritten name to use...

---

It looks like this doesn't happen for any value of `var`. It does happen though if the key is named `default`, because SoyToJsSrcCompiler generates code using `'default'` (for this special name only, not for any other name I used so far), thus preventing Closure Compiler from renaming it, but the property is renamed in the JavaScript code, because I'm using `default` without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your template looks something like:

```
/**
 * Foo
 * @param rec
 */
{template .Foo}
    <div>{$rec.var}</div>
{/template}
```

Then the SoyToJsSrcCompiler will produce code similar to:

```
/**
 * @param {Object.<string, *>=} opt_data
 * @param {(null|undefined)=} opt_ignored
 * @return {string}
 * @notypecheck
 */
namespace.Foo = function(opt_data, opt_ignored) {
  return '<div>' + soy.$$escapeHtml(opt_data.rec.var) + '</div>';
};
```

This generated template function is meant to be included in the compilation with your source file. Since the output property access is of the form `rec.var` the compiler should rename it correctly.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to work (as I would have expected it to). But now I see what the problem really is. If a property is named `default`, then the code generated by SoyToJsSrcCompiler writes it as `['default']`, but the property gets renamed in the original object by the Closure Compiler... Maybe this happens because `default` is a reserved word, and I'm guessing that the soy compiler is afraid of breaking the syntax if it's not quoting it (even though `rec.default` is perfectly valid syntax)... Can I work around this in a way that doesn't involve renaming my property?

Comment: What you describe should only happen if in the original template you use syntax like `{$rec['var']}`. In that case, you need to call your template like `namespace.foo({rec: {'var': val}})` to avoid the mixed property access issues you are currently seeing.

Comment: The template contains something similar to `{$rec.foo.default.bar}`, which generates the code `opt_data.rec.foo['default'].bar`. It seems that it only uses quotes for the name `default`, but not for anything else.

Comment: We've gone from in general, to very specific. Can you please post your template?

Comment: Sure, I'll create a separate question.